# How to compute the power of Wilcoxon test?

Tags: statistical-power, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am using Wilcoxon test to compare two paired sets of data for whether their means differ. Besides the p-value, I would also like to know the power of this test. How to compute it in R? Thank you in advance.

Comment: One comment: The wilcoxon signed rank test, tests the hypothesis that the MEDIANS differ I do believe. http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statsignedrank.html

Comment: B_Miner, no, it is for means.  There is an assumption of balance around the median but the medians is not what you're comparing.

Comment: The power depends on the shape of the true distribution of the pairwise differences. You have to specify your assumption what kind of distribution this is.

Comment: @john - is the source I cite incorrect?

Comment: B_Miner... I did a few quick searches.  An intro stats text next to me, a Vassar site, and Wikipedia support my assertion.  Nevertheless, there are a couple of 'handbooks' like the one you cited that do state it's about differences between medians.  I didn't read them all carefully but now I'm thinking about it and I'm wondering if it actually matters.  In fact, the NIST reference I found didn't even mention means or medians. hmmmm... probably more time than I want to spend on this topic until I actually want to do one of these.

Comment: @B_Miner what your link *actually* says is "*median difference between pairs of observations*" (which is correct). That's not the same as the difference in medians of the groups; I believe you simply misinterpreted the phrase.

Comment: @eJohn The signed rank test does not compare means. Nor strictly speaking does it compare medians. (It's quite easy to demonstrate that it does neither.) If you add some assumptions - ones already required under the null anyway - it serves to compare either medians or means however (providing means exist).

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if there's an analytical solution to your question, but when all else fails, one can simulate the distribution you *think* the two samples come from many thousands of times using Monte Carlo methods. The percentage of those samples the Wilcoxon test correctly identifies as "different" is the power of the test. For example, if you generated 10,000 different simulated paired samples that match your actual data in terms of size and the distribution they came from, and 8,000 of them are correctly identified by the test as different, your power = 0.80.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have Ho: median <= 8 and Ha: median > 8
As par for the course, remove any values from your data equal to 8.
Calculate the sample mean and sample standard deviation. Use the sample mean as your alternate mean for the power calculation.
In my data, n=9 (df = 8) and I'm testing at alpha = 5%. The t critical value is 1.86.
Also, the sample mean from my data is 12.7333333... and the sample standard deviation is 7.79527429.
Calculate X1 = 1.86(7.97527429)/sqrt(9) + 8 = 12.94467006
Calculate t1 = 12.94467006 - 12.733333.... = 0.211336726
Then, power = P(t > 0.211336726) = 0.491 based on df = 8.

I found this procedure here:
https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Wilcoxon_Signed-Rank_Tests.pdf
However, they are using a non-central t distribution which only complicates the matter.

Comment: This pair of hypotheses is not the same as testing whether the medians differ. Also,  using means to compute the power will need justification.